# Measure dB with AVAudioRecorder is limited to 96dB on iOS

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, bitrate, decibel

I'm trying to build a dB Measurement to unlock a feature within an app. The Feature should become available once the user reaches 100dB. My current implementation is only able to measure up to 96dB. From what I understand the Problem is somehow related to the bitrate recording: 16bit are only capable of 96dB, 24bit should be capable of 144dB (http://www.head-fi.org/t/415361/24bit-vs-16bit-the-myth-exploded).

The dB Measurement and Calculations work fine, my only issue is that I can not measure more than 96dB. I'm struggeling with the settings to achieve a higher bit rate, I guess I'm doing something wrong here.

My current initialisation of the recorder looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4],       AVFormatIDKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                      //[NSNumber numberWithInt: 24],                         AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:24],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                      nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:settings error:&error];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that a `dB` value is just an expression of a *ratio*, not an absolute value. In this case it's the magnitude of the signal relative to the smallest value, so for a 16 bit signed value you have `20 * log10(2^16) = 96 dB`. In other words the loudest signal is 96 dB louder than the smallest signal. With 24 bit data the range is much bigger: `20 * log10(2^24) = 144 dB`. However the full scale signal is still the same *value*. (Note that more commonly we use *full scale* as a reference of `0 dB`, and express all other values as negative `dB` values, but the reference is completely arbitrary).

A common source of confusion is that when people talk about how loud *sound* is, they say "dB" but what they are actually referring to is [dB SPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level), which is way of defining loudness *relative to a given reference value* (20 µPa (rms)). Do not confuse this with the `dB` values you are calculating above, which are simple ratios, and are not directly related to loudness.

Comment: Thank you, understood. As I mentioned my formulas work great but the averagePowerForChannel Value is something between 0 and -160. My Problem is currently that I reach the 0 (loudest) value at around 96dB (compared to other decibel measurement apps). Did you manage to change your input signal to 24bit somehow? (Or do I not need to? The settings in my initial post doesn't look like to show any affect on the data range)

Comment: I think you're still not getting the point about `dB` being a *ratio*, and hence *arbitrary*. Those "other apps" are not reporting `dB SPL` - they are just returning a `dB` value relative to some arbitrary reference. You can add or subtract any `dB` offset you like to make your values match and the numbers will be just as valid. If your problem is *range* though, then note anything more than about 96 dB on a consumer device is a joke - you can perhaps set audio resolution to 24 bits but the noise floor will prevent you getting any greater range than you see at 16 bits.